# Hazelcast add members at runtime

Tags: java, cluster-computing, hazelcast

I have created one cluster

```java
private static final String IP_CLUSTER = "192.168.0.116:5701";

Config cfg = new Config();
// set IP of cluster
cfg.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember(IP_CLUSTER).setEnabled(true);
cfg.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);    
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
```

now i try with `hazelcast-client` to connect this cluster

```java
HazelcastInstance clientInstance = null;
try {
    ClientConfig cfg = new ClientConfig();
    ClientNetworkConfig cnc = cfg.getNetworkConfig();
    // ip of cluster that i want to connect
    cnc.addAddress(IP_CLUSTER);
    clientInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(cfg);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    return;
}
```

when i try to connect the client, i become on client following output

> Jun 19, 2017 8:19:51 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
>   INFORMATION: [192.168.0.116]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] [192.168.0.116]:5701
>   is STARTED Jun 19, 2017 8:19:56 PM
>   com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.SocketAcceptorThread INFORMATION:
>   [192.168.0.116]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Accepting socket connection from
>   /192.168.0.116:60200 Jun 19, 2017 8:19:56 PM
>   com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager INFORMATION:
>   [192.168.0.116]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Established socket connection
>   between /192.168.0.116:5701 and /192.168.0.116:60200 Jun 19, 2017
>   8:19:56 PM
>   com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AuthenticationMessageTask
>   INFORMATION: [192.168.0.116]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Received auth from
>   Connection[id=1, /192.168.0.116:5701->/192.168.0.116:60200,
>   endpoint=null, alive=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT], successfully
>   authenticated, principal :
>   ClientPrincipal{uuid='adaf4c23-a708-489b-9480-dfc7edf960ce',
>   ownerUuid='02d591cc-b572-4e6e-8904-92bd0d8c3610'}, owner connection :
>   true, client version : 3.7.8 Jun 19, 2017 8:20:07 PM
>   com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
>   INFORMATION: [192.168.0.116]:5701 [dev] [3.7.8] Initializing cluster
>   partition table arrangement...

means -> new member is connected to cluster. Is it correct?

but when i ask for count of members on cluster, it is always `1`

Where i have a mistake?
How to add new members (`HazelcastInstances`) to cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its realy strange to understand, but by many time excution of

```
private static final String IP_CLUSTER = "192.168.0.116:5701";

Config cfg = new Config();
// set IP of cluster
cfg.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember(IP_CLUSTER).setEnabled(true);
cfg.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);    
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
```

there would be:

- first execution - creates a cluster and add one node to it
- each next execution - adds a node to existing cluster

Comment: What is strange about that? You need at least one known member address to join a cluster, that said, every other member you start (and hand in the address of the first member, the one that created the cluster) will join the existing cluster.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned yourself you connected a Hazelcast client to the (one-node) cluster. A client is just a client but not a cluster node. Imagine it as a JDBC client connecting to a database. To scale the cluster you need to start additional Hazelcast members.

```
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(); // <- creates nodes

HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(); // <- creates a client
```

Comment: hi. you´re right. But how to create new instance on `cluster-client` ? the config is on client not editable

Comment: Not sure I get your question.

Comment: i want to connect many nodes to cluster. I have 10 pc's that are in one network. on one of them i create a cluster and on others i want to connect to cluster and each pc shold have one node

Comment: So just create more nodes and set up the ip addresses of at least one other (reachable) node.